# How to store my datetime as a date in my database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date

**Goal**: I want to save some data from an api to my database, the date looks like this in the api:

```
"utcDate": "2018-10-28T13:30:00Z"
```

I tried using datetime in my migrations but I'm getting errors that this is not the right format.

```
$table->datetime('date');
```

**My error:**

```
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2018-10-20T11:30:00Z' for column 'date' at row 1")
```

Any other ways of storing this date as date in my database?

Comment: or dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357284/mysql-how-to-convert-date-from-iso-8601-format-and-save-to-mysql-column

Comment: This is *NOT* a dupe--Laravel/MySQL doesn't require Eloquent models to be converted to Unix timestamps. Eloquent formats the value for the database automatically when provided a DateTime object, so there's no need to convert anything beyond getting the date string into a DateTime object in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert it to `date` form `datetime` using `DateTime` before going to insert the value, It is causing error because `$table->datetime('date');` doen't work for you to convert it to `date` format. Also you can use MYSQL [DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to cast it to `date` from `datetime`.

```
<?php

$datetime = "2018-10-28T13:30:00Z";
$date = new DateTime($datetime);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php
$datetime = "2018-10-28T13:30:00Z";
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datetime));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this query is simple to do it by use `DATE()` method from MySQL

```
    INSERT INTO `test`
    (`createdAt`)
    VALUES
    (DATE('2018-01-01 07:00:01'));
```