# String to Date-time in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to convert a column having data such as 2021-05-01T04:41:01.736Z in string format to date-time?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. MySQL can parse that date format automatically. Except it ignores the `Z` timezone specifier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql - How to convert date from ISO 8601 format and save to mysql column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357284/mysql-how-to-convert-date-from-iso-8601-format-and-save-to-mysql-column)